# How to restore Visual Studio user settings (after possible accidental synchronise)

Tags: visual-studio

Somehow - I'm guessing it was to do with a test installation of MS Visual Studio Community 2017 that synchronized using my Microsoft account - I have had my user settings changed in an identical and annoying way on two separate systems running MS Visual Studio 2015 Community. In any case, settings affecting display of line numbers, indentation, spacing, and more have all changed. Where are these settings stored and how can I get them back to the way I prefer? I would hope I can restore a previous version of the appropriate file(s)... if only I knew what they were and where to find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Settings`

VS2015 settings can be found here.

As the op said you can get previous version via restore of previous state of the files.

Then proceed to import them via Tools -> Import & Export Settings

Beware of the sync functionality while logged in, to avoid issues.

Comment: I used Windows "Restore Previous Versions" to get a copy of this folder from a week ago, restored it, close then reopened Visual Studio... but with no effect. Do you know if settings are re-synchronized on startup? The current settings in this folder certainly had its date modified when I restarted Visual Studio :-(

Comment: @omatai You have to import these settings in VS via Tools => "Import and Export settings"

Comment: Plus if you are logged in, you will have to log out yourself to avoid the re-sync.

Comment: @omatai did the import fix it?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure... but I believe so. I am no longer annoyed by the strange settings, and I did both disable sync and import these settings. But I was too focused on using VS to get a job done, so am not clear about the precise point at which things returned to normal (or at least acceptable).